# How to install composer on Linux to be able to run the Laravel New command

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php

I would like to know how to install composer with the vendor/bin folder to be able to run the `laravel new project` as describe in the laravel docs and not only install the composer binary for install and update packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this command :

**install composer in `/usr/bin`**

> php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
>
> php composer-setup.php --filename=composer --install-dir=/usr/bin

**install Laravel installer**

> composer global require laravel/installer

Make sure your Env path variable have :

> $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin

Comment: Super, happy to help.